# innerHTML append in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-9, innerhtml

I have a page that simply tries to do the following in a javascript function:

```
document.getElementById("chatTable").innerHTML += "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">      ⏎
    <span color=\"purple\">------------Switched to channel: " + channelName +  ⏎
    "------------</span></td></tr>";
```

This works in every other browser I have tried (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Android phone browsers, iPhone browsers) but not in IE9. Yes, I do have a table with the ID `chatTable` and the `channelName` variable is indeed set. I understand I may be able to actually append a table row using the DOM for the Table Object (I think its `insertRow()` or something) but now it has just became a matter of principle, and its been driving me nuts. I have tried changing the `+=` to just `=` and no luck. I also tried setting the table to its own variable in javascript and THEN trying to edit the innerHTML and still no luck. Oh and I do have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

in my page. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Did the Javascript file execute after the document is loaded ? Any error in browser's development console ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `.innerHTML` or `.outerHTML` with any of the following elements: COL, COLGROUP, FRAMESET, HTML, STYLE, TABLE, TBODY, TFOOT, THEAD, TITLE, or TR.

See [Building Tables Dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to use Microsoft's Table Object Model to manipulate tables in Internet Explorer.

This could change in future versions of IE, I suppose, but this is what you're left with for now.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me! I am now building the table in javascript rather than appending to the innerHTML and it is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jim's answer, when you append HTML, you destroy and rebuild the existing table.  Even in browsers that let you do this, the generally better solution to add a row is this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("chatTable"),
    row = table.insertRow(-1), //-1 means at end
    cell = row.insertCell(0),
    span = document.createElement("span");

span.style.color = "purple";
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("------------Switched to channel: " + channelName + "------------"));
cell.colSpan = 3;
cell.appendChild(span);
row.appendChild(cell);
table.appendChild(row);
```

It is generally faster and you don't lose any existing event handlers you have attached to things in the table.

Comment: Thank you for the code! Works beautifully. 
One note though

        setAttribute("color", "purple");
Doesn't work, you need to do:

        setAttribute("style", "color:purple;");

But other than that its perfect, thank you!